# Prolog program structure for constraint solution analysis

Tags: prolog, constraints, constraint-programming

I have a SWI-PROLOG program with the following structure:

```
% various predicates
...
...
...

main :-
   % constraints
   ...
   ...
   ...
   % labeling of about 50 variables
   label([........]),
   % additional conditions and constraints:
   condition1
   condition2
   ...
   conditionN
   % output
   write(Interesting_var),nl.
```

The constraint solver works reasonably fast (for about 10 seconds) and finds many answers.  Then I can filter the answers with the help of `condition1`,...,`conditionN` and print `Interesting_var`.

**Problem 1:** I have to run this many times with different `condition1`,...,`conditionN`. So I am modifying the program each time I run it.  But what if the constraints were solved not for 10 seconds but for 10 minutes or 10 hours?  How can I remember all solutions of the constraints and then ask specific questions about the values of about 50 interesting variables in the constraints.

**Problem 2:** I have about 50 interesting variables at present. But I am constantly adding new variables and new constraints. The `main` predicate is getting longer and longer... How can I make my program more modular. Semantically these variables can be grouped into few "domains", however in my program they all are defined in one place.

Comment: Why are you posting the constraints in separate phases? It is typically more efficient to first post all constraints, and then label the variables.

Comment: The first constraints compute the possible "worlds". Condition1,...,conditionN are the question I ask and I am changing them all the time.

Comment: Still, you could also repost all constraints together! This may help to reduce the search space a lot.